# Return positions of a regex match() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, string-matching

Is there a way to retrieve the (starting) character positions inside a string of the results of a regex match() in Javascript?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```js
// Finds starting and ending positions of quoted text
// in double or single quotes with escape char support like \" \'
var str = "this is a \"quoted\" string as you can 'read'";

var patt = /'((?:\\.|[^'])*)'|"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"/igm;

while (match = patt.exec(str)) {
  console.log(match.index + ' ' + patt.lastIndex);
}
```

Comment: `match.index + match[0].length` also works for the end position.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin, wouldn't the end position be `match.index + match[0].length - 1`?

Comment: @David, I meant exclusive end position, as taken e.g. by `.slice()` and `.substring()`.  Inclusive end would be 1 less as you say. (Be careful that inclusive usually means index of last char inside match, unless it's an empty match where it's 1 *before* match and might be `-1` outside the string entirely for empty match at start...)

Comment: for `patt = /.*/` it goes infinity loop how can we restrict that?

Answer (score 309):

[`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns an object with a `index` property:

```js
var match = /bar/.exec("foobar");
if (match) {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

And for multiple matches:

```js
var re = /bar/g,
    str = "foobarfoobar";
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you tell me also how do I find the indexes of multiple matches?

Comment: @stagas: In that case you should better use `exec`.

Comment: `match()` does not have any `index` property. The result is an `Array`.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım It’s meant to be `exec` as shown in the second example.

Comment: Note: using the `re` as a variable, and adding the `g` modifier are both crucial! Otherwise you will get an endless loop.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım - According to the `String.prototype.match()` docs on mozilla it does. It specifically states that the returned Array has an added `index` property that represents the zero-based match location in the string.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım - I'm telling you it wasn't wrong in the first place, the return of `match()` DOES have an `index` property. You do not need to use `exec`

Comment: @OnurYıldırım - It specifically states that the returned `Array` has the `index` property added. Here's the quote from the docs: _In addition, it has an index property, which represents the zero-based index of the match in the string._ You can find it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Description

Comment: @JimboJonny, you're right MDN says that. But test it. It does not have any `index` property.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım - here's a jsfiddle of it working...I've tested it all the way back to IE5...works great: https://jsfiddle.net/6uwn1vof/

Comment: @JimboJonny, hm well I learned something new. My test case returns `undefined`. https://jsfiddle.net/6uwn1vof/2/  which is not a search-like example like yours.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım - Remove the `g` flag and it'll work. Since `match` is a function of the string, not the regex it cannot be stateful like `exec`, so it only treats it like `exec` (i.e. has an index property) if you're not looking for a global match...because then statefulness doesn't matter.

Comment: In TypeScript it has to be (example) `let match = /(&)\1+/g.exec(this.label);
            let indexes: number[] = [];
            while (match) {
                indexes.push(match.index);
                this.label = this.label.replace(/(&)\1+/, '');
                match = /(&)\1+/g.exec(this.label);
            }`

Comment: Am I the only one? you are setting match inside the while loop. You didn't define it though. Thus, you set `window.match` and after the loop this variable is set to `null`, instead of `undefined`. Generally, stay away from setting variables inside loops, bad practice, and this answer is a good example why it is a bad practice. Just harder to read.

Comment: @JimboJonny Intrigued by your comment that the `g` flag could be removed and it still work, I can report that it does not (or it does, but it creates an infinite loop) -- 0/10 would not recommend (up-to-date Chrome browser: Version 89.0.4389.90)

Comment: See my issue with matching regexes of width 0 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67947861/1207489. Feel free to copy the lines about `re.lastIndex++` to your solution.

Comment: @Steven My comments were about the `match` function, in response to another commenter saying `match` returns an Array and therefore doesn't have an `index` property. In reality `match` does return an Array, but with an `index` property added _specifically_ when you remove the `g` flag.  Just tested it today and it's as true as it was a decade ago (2 decades ago if you count that it worked all the way back to IE5).

Comment: @JimboJonny my mistake, I must have not noticed you weren't replying directly to the answer posted

Comment: @Steven I've fallen in the same pitfall. `match`, even when not global, will always start its search from the beginning, because of the lack of statefulness. So the logical conclusion is: If you want to receive the index of all matches, you can only manually iterate using `exec`, because only then you are stateful within the RegExp object, which becomes necessary. You cannot extract all match indices from a string-on-string search. JS at its finest. Who thought that an index property for the first hit would be enough?

Answer (score 33):

In modern browsers, you can accomplish this with [string.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll).

The benefit to this approach vs `RegExp.exec()` is that it does not rely on the regex being stateful, as in [@Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295681/1569320).

```js
let regexp = /bar/g;
let str = 'foobarfoobar';

let matches = [...str.matchAll(regexp)];
matches.forEach((match) => {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
});
```

Comment: I had luck using this single-line solution based on `matchAll`

```
    let regexp = /bar/g;
    let str = 'foobarfoobar';
    let matchIndices = Array.from(str.matchAll(regexp)).map(x => x.index);
    console.log(matchIndices)```

Comment: not sure why you say this approach does not rely on the regex being stateful. I try your code without `g` flag and get error

Comment: The "g" flag means "global search", i.e. match all occurrences in the string. It doesn't make sense to use str.matchAll() if you're not doing a global search. Hopefully that helps, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

With my "stateful" comment, I mean that you don't have to use a "while" loop and rely on the internal state of the Regexp object, as in Gumbo's answer, which I linked. Good luck!

Answer (score 28):

From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) docs on the String `.match()` method:

> The returned Array has an extra input property, which contains the
> original string that was parsed. In addition, **it has an index
> property, which represents the zero-based index of the match in the
> string**.

When dealing with a non-global regex (i.e., no `g` flag on your regex), the value returned by `.match()` has an `index` property...all you have to do is access it.

```
var index = str.match(/regex/).index;
```

Here is an example showing it working as well:

```js
var str = 'my string here';

var index = str.match(/here/).index;

console.log(index); // <- 10
```

I have successfully tested this all the way back to IE5.

Comment: This returns an array, not an object with index on it

Comment: @BenTaliadoros I'm afraid you're wrong, it is *both* and array and an object with `index` property (see the answer)

Comment: Seems so! Not sure what I was thinking all those years ago

Comment: Note that if you do str.match(/here/g), with the global flag, match.index will be undefined.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `search` method of the `String` object. This will only work for the first match, but will otherwise do what you describe. For example:

```
"How are you?".search(/are/);
// 4
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a cool feature I discovered recently, I tried this on the console and it seems to work:

```
var text = "border-bottom-left-radius";

var newText = text.replace(/-/g,function(match, index){
    return " " + index + " ";
});
```

Which returned: "border 6 bottom 13 left 18 radius"

So this seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: just beware that replacement functions add capture groups as well, so note that it's always the *second-to-last* entry in the replacement function `arguments` that is the position. Not "the second argument". The function arguments are "full match, group1, group2, ...., index of match, full string matched against"

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid the previous answers (based on `exec`) don't seem to work in case your regex matches width 0. For instance (Note: `/\b/g` is the regex that should find all word boundaries) :

```js
var re = /\b/g,
    str = "hello world";
var guard = 10;
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
    if (guard-- < 0) {
      console.error("Infinite loop detected")
      break;
    }
}
```

One can try to fix this by having the regex match at least 1 character, but this is far from ideal (and means you have to manually add the index at the end of the string)

```js
var re = /\b./g,
    str = "hello world";
var guard = 10;
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
    if (guard-- < 0) {
      console.error("Infinite loop detected")
      break;
    }
}
```

A better solution (which does only work on newer browsers / needs polyfills on older/IE versions) is to use [String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

```js
var re = /\b/g,
    str = "hello world";
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(re)).map(match => match.index))
```

Explanation:

String.prototype.matchAll() expects a global regex (one with `g` of global flag set). It then returns an iterator. In order to loop over and `map()` the iterator, it has to be turned into an array (which is exactly what `Array.from()` does). Like the result of `RegExp.prototype.exec()`, the resulting elements have an `.index` field according to the specification.

See the [String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and the [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) MDN pages for browser support and polyfill options.

---

Edit: *digging a little deeper in search for a solution supported on all browsers*

The problem with `RegExp.prototype.exec()` is that it updates the `lastIndex` pointer on the regex, and next time starts searching from the previously found `lastIndex`.

```js
var re = /l/g,
str = "hello world";
console.log(re.lastIndex)
re.exec(str)
console.log(re.lastIndex)
re.exec(str)
console.log(re.lastIndex)
re.exec(str)
console.log(re.lastIndex)
```

This works great as long as the regex match actually has a width. If using a 0 width regex, this pointer does not increase, and so you get your infinite loop (note: `/(?=l)/g` is a lookahead for l -- it matches the 0-width string before an `l`. So it correctly goes to index 2 on the first call of `exec()`, and then stays there:

```js
var re = /(?=l)/g,
str = "hello world";
console.log(re.lastIndex)
re.exec(str)
console.log(re.lastIndex)
re.exec(str)
console.log(re.lastIndex)
re.exec(str)
console.log(re.lastIndex)
```

The solution (that is less nice than matchAll(), but should work on all browsers) therefore is to manually increase the lastIndex if the match width is 0 (which may be checked in different ways)

```js
var re = /\b/g,
    str = "hello world";
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);

    // alternative: if (match.index == re.lastIndex) {
    if (match[0].length == 0) {
      // we need to increase lastIndex -- this location was already matched,
      // we don't want to match it again (and get into an infinite loop)
      re.lastIndex++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This member fn returns an array of 0-based positions, if any, of the input word inside the String object

```
String.prototype.matching_positions = function( _word, _case_sensitive, _whole_words, _multiline )
{
   /*besides '_word' param, others are flags (0|1)*/
   var _match_pattern = "g"+(_case_sensitive?"i":"")+(_multiline?"m":"") ;
   var _bound = _whole_words ? "\\b" : "" ;
   var _re = new RegExp( _bound+_word+_bound, _match_pattern );
   var _pos = [], _chunk, _index = 0 ;

   while( true )
   {
      _chunk = _re.exec( this ) ;
      if ( _chunk == null ) break ;
      _pos.push( _chunk['index'] ) ;
      _re.lastIndex = _chunk['index']+1 ;
   }

   return _pos ;
}
```

Now try

```
var _sentence = "What do doers want ? What do doers need ?" ;
var _word = "do" ;
console.log( _sentence.matching_positions( _word, 1, 0, 0 ) );
console.log( _sentence.matching_positions( _word, 1, 1, 0 ) );
```

You can also input regular expressions:

```
var _second = "z^2+2z-1" ;
console.log( _second.matching_positions( "[0-9]\z+", 0, 0, 0 ) );
```

Here one gets the position index of linear term.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";

function searchIndex(str, searchValue, isCaseSensitive) {
  var modifiers = isCaseSensitive ? 'gi' : 'g';
  var regExpValue = new RegExp(searchValue, modifiers);
  var matches = [];
  var startIndex = 0;
  var arr = str.match(regExpValue);

  [].forEach.call(arr, function(element) {
    startIndex = str.indexOf(element, startIndex);
    matches.push(startIndex++);
  });

  return matches;
}

console.log(searchIndex(str, 'ain', true));
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `str.indexOf` here just finds the next occurrence of the text captured by the match, which is not necessarily the match. JS regex supports conditions on text outside of the capture with lookahead. For instance `searchIndex("foobarfoobaz", "foo(?=baz)", true)` should give `[6]`, not `[0]`.

Comment: why ` [].forEach.call(arr, function(element)` why not arr.forEach or arr.map

Answer (score 2):

I had luck using this single-line solution based on `matchAll` (my use case  needs an array of string positions)

```
let regexp = /bar/g;
let str = 'foobarfoobar';

let matchIndices = Array.from(str.matchAll(regexp)).map(x => x.index);

console.log(matchIndices)
```

output: [3, 9]

Answer (score 0):

```
function trimRegex(str, regex){
    return str.substr(str.match(regex).index).split('').reverse().join('').substr(str.match(regex).index).split('').reverse().join('');
}

let test = '||ab||cd||';
trimRegex(test, /[^|]/);
console.log(test); //output: ab||cd
```

or

```
function trimChar(str, trim, req){
    let regex = new RegExp('[^'+trim+']');
    return str.substr(str.match(regex).index).split('').reverse().join('').substr(str.match(regex).index).split('').reverse().join('');
}

let test = '||ab||cd||';
trimChar(test, '|');
console.log(test); //output: ab||cd
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var str = 'my string here';

var index = str.match(/hre/).index;

alert(index); // <- 10
```

Comment: So just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296438/402037) from 4 years ago (which, unlike yours, works)