# How to get both the start and end positions of regex matches in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I just wish to find the start and end positions of the substrings I am searching for.
Any Ideas as to how this can be done?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it fail? What mark-up or JavaScript are you using?

Comment: Questions that don't show that the OP put any effort really make me sad.

Comment: I agree Juan, and it seems all too common with userNNNNNN accounts in particular.

Comment: @JuanMendes We shouldn't criticize people for asking useful questions like this one: the answer wasn't obvious to me either, so I'm grateful that this question was posted.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Like it or not, a question without effort is a poor one. If you do that at work, you won't get anywhere. Asking to show what you tried is constructive citicism. I don't think anyone was rude. Asking questions without showing enough effort is impolite if you ask me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return positions of a regex match() in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a jsfiddle that shows how it's done...

https://jsfiddle.net/cz8vqgba/

```
var regex = /text/g;
var text = 'this is some text and then there is some more text';
var match;
while(match = regex.exec(text)){
    console.log('start index= ' +(regex.lastIndex - match[0].length));   
    console.log('end index= ' + (regex.lastIndex-1));
}
```

This will get you the start and end index of all matches in the string...

Answer (score 7):

no need at all to traverse the haystack two times (which would likely be less efficient)

you can do either:

```
"foobarfoobar".match(/bar/);
```

or:

```
/bar/.exec("foobarfoobar");
```

both return this object :

```
{
    0: 'bar'
    index: 3
    input: 'foobarfoobar'
}
```

so if you want start and end positions, you just have to do something like:

```
var needle = /bar/;
var haystack = 'foobarfoobar';

var result = needle.exec(haystack);
var start = result.index;
var end = start + result[0].length - 1;
```

Note this simple example gives you only the first match; if you expect several matches, things get a little bit more complicated.

Also, I answered for regex as it is in the title of the question, but if all you need is string match you can do nearly the same with indexOf().