# The exec() method never returns null with certains regex

Tags: javascript

For example i want to get the first character of a string using the '^' meta char.
This will make the following code crash because exec() never returns null.
Is there a way to make it works without changing the regex ? (At least not crash ?)

```
const regexp = /^/g;
const str = 'Lorem ipsum';
let regexMatches = [];

 while ((matches = regexp.exec(str)) !== null) {
   regexMatches.push({str: matches[0], index: regexp.lastIndex});
 }
```

Comment: `^` doesn't match the first character! It matches the beginning of the string (or a line with multi-line (`m`) modifier)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21436580/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the `lastIndex` from the previous match. If it doesn't change, break out of the loop.

```
let prevIndex = -1;
while ((matches = regexp.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (regexp.lastIndex == prevIndex) { // no movement
        break;
    }
    regexMatches.push({str: matches[0], index: regexp.lastIndex});
    prevIndex = regexp.lastIndex;
}
```

Comment: Don't break, but rather advance by one position. There might be more matches elsewhere.