# Regex to match all " - " deliminators in filename except first and last?

Tags: regex

I've been trying to write a regex to match all the " - " deliminators in a filename except the first and last, so I can combine all the data in the middle into one group, for example a filename like:

```
Ann M Martin - Baby sitters Club - Baby sitters Little Sister - Super Special 04 - Karen, Hannie and Nancy - The Three Musketeers.doc
```

Has to become:

```
Ann M Martin - Baby sitters Club- Baby sitters Little Sister- Super Special 04- Karen, Hannie and Nancy - The Three Musketeers.doc
```

So basically I'm trying to replace " - " with "- " but not the first or last instance. The Filenames can have 1 to 6 " - " deliminators, but should only affect the ones with 3, 4, 5 or 6 " - " deliminators.

It's for use in File Renamer. flavor is JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: `Deliminators` *I'LL BE BOCK*

Comment: deliminator isn't a word.

Answer (score 1):

Can you *not* use a regex? If so:

```
var s = "Ann M Martin - Baby sitters Club - Baby sitters Little Sister - Super Special 04 - Karen, Hannie and Nancy - The Three Musketeers.doc";
var p = s.split(' - ');
var r = ''; // result output
var i = 0;
p.forEach(function(e){
  switch(i) {
    case 0: r += e; break;
    case 1: case p.length - 1: r += ' - ' + e; break;
    default: r += '- ' + e;
  }
  i++;
});
console.log(r);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7zcp8z6/1/

```
s=Ann M Martin - Baby sitters Club - Baby sitters Little Sister - Super Special 04 - Karen, Hannie and Nancy - The Three Musketeers.doc
r=Ann M Martin - Baby sitters Club- Baby sitters Little Sister- Super Special 04- Karen, Hannie and Nancy - The Three Musketeers.doc
```

This is assuming that the separator is always `-` (1 space, 1 dash, 1 space). If not, you need to split on `-` only, then trim each tokens before reconstructing.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1 - You'll need to do some processing of your own by iterating through the matches using

```
( - )
```

and building a new string (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript) about getting match indices).

You'll have to check that the match count is greater than 2 and skip the first and last matches.

2 - Use

```
.+ - ((?:.+ - )+).+ - .+
```

to get the part of the string to be modified and then do a replace on the the dashes, then build your string (again using the indices from the above regex).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.

[I got it to work this way](http://regex101.com/r/aZ6bM2/1)

It replaces the first and last " - " with " ! ", so I can then do a simple Find and Replace of all remaining " - " with "- ", then change all the " ! " back to " - "