# how to find '/' character using expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, match

i want to get the index of all string '/jk' from the string 'ujj/jkiiiii/jk' using JavaScript and match function.I am able to find all string but when i am using / ,it is showing error.

Comment: ` 'ujj/jkiiiii/jk'.indexOf( "/jk" )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return positions of a regex match() in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript)

Comment: Show us the code where you are trying to find the indexes

Comment: var string='ujj/jkiiiii/jk';   var regex = //jk/gi, result, indices = [];
    while ((result = regex.exec(string))) {
        indices.push(result.index);
    }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get an array of positions of '/jk' in a string you can either use regular expressions:

```
var str = 'ujj/jkiiiii/jk'
var re = /\/jk/g
var indices = []
var found
while (found = re.exec(str)) {
    indices.push(found.index)
}
```

Here `/\/jk/g` is a regular expression that matches '/jk' (/ is escaped so it is `\/`). Learn regular expressions at http://regexr.com/.

Or you can use str.indexOf(), but you'll need a loop anyway:

```
var str = 'ujj/jkiiiii/jk'
var substr = '/jk'
var indices = []
var index = 0 - substr.length
while ((index = str.indexOf(substr, index + substr.length)) != -1) {
    indices.push(index)
}
```

The result in both cases will be [3, 11] in `indices` variable.

Answer (score -1):

I update my answer.

you just need to add a '\' when you want to find a '/' because '\' is the escape character.
As you don't give any clue of what you want to do. This is what I can help. If you update your answer with your code I can help a little more.

Comment: It will return only the first index of 'jk' not all.

Comment: Show an example without "/". So, I can see what you want.

But try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Comment: You can check out example here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410464/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-one-string-in-another-in-javascript. Here all the strings are working good,but what if the string contains '/' character then how to make regx.

Comment: I update my answer. to be more general as you need(without code)