# Counting sub-strings

Tags: javascript, regex

If you want to count the number of occurrences of one string inside another, which approach is better in terms of simplicity and/or performance? -

- using `indexOf` in a `for`/`while` loop
- using a regular expression

And if it is the latter, then what is the best way to do it?

Comment: @vitaly-t Implement [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) if performance is vital.

Comment: @user340764, that answers the question indeed, thank you. I probably should just delete it then?

Comment: @vitaly-t if you need to delete string after finding their indexes, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript) link might be useful.

Comment: just wondering how using split() then counting the size of the resulting array would fare.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regular expression:

```js
var temp = "This is a string.";

var count = (temp.match(/is/g) || []).length;
alert(count);
```

Comment: It is good, but I wanted to know which way is better. That link provided earlier answers it fully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string