# Regex match error in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I have seen [Return positions of a regex match() in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript) but not sure how to implement it in my case

I have an array `item_array` and I want to filter all items containing text `val`

This is the code I'm using :

I have made a function `matchdata` to filter the results

```
var matchdata = function(text_to_match, item_array) {
    var reg = new RegExp(text_to_match.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    return item_array.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.match(reg)) {
            return item;
        }
    });
};
```

And I'm using it like

```
var matching_items = matchdata(val, item_array);
```

Now I have 2 questions :

1. When `val` ( item to find in array ) contains more than one `\`, it starts giving this error in console :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\w*\w*/: \ at end of pattern(…)

Why is this happening ? and is there any way to rectify this ?

2. Is there any way the `filter` function can return the *matched item index* along with the *matched item* ( assuming there can be duplicate entries in the array )

Comment: can you explain the downvote ?

Comment: When `text_to_match = "\\\\"`, your `split & join` will try to create an invalid regex

Comment: It would be more informative if you can provide example inputfr for `text_to_match` and `items_array`.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R : you can see this https://jsfiddle.net/pjtnpLn7/3/ for an example

Comment: @Guedes : thanks for informing, do you have a solution for this ? and by index, i mean the array index of the matched item

Comment: @mrid. Instead of split, try `.match(/\\.|./g)`

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to regex and still learning, so found this somewhere while searching and it was working so i thought it must be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is your *'regex idea'* coded in a for-loop:

```
function isSubstring (input, text) {
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    var found = 0;
    var nextChar = input.charAt(found);
    for (var i=0, l=text.length; i<l; i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) === nextChar) {
            found++;
            if (found === input.length)
                return true;
            nextChar = input.charAt(found);
        }
    }
};
```

Basically, it will look for a substring with zero or more characters between each matched letter:

```
isSubstring('BZL', 'Brazil');  // true
//                  ^  ^ ^
```

Then, your code will look like:

```
var matchdata = function(text_to_match, item_array) {
    var result = item_array.map(function(item, index) {
        if (isSubstring(text_to_match, item)) {
            return [item, index];
        }
        return 0;
    });
    return result.filter(isNaN);
};
```

The `result` will be a matrix:

```
matchdata('bzl', ['BraZiL', 'LiZarB', 'BraZiL']);
// [ ['brazil', 0], ['brazil', 2] ]
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: what does `result.filter(isNaN)` do ?

Comment: The `map` function returns `0` when `isSubstring(text_to_match, item)` is not true. Since `isNaN(0) === false`, you can use `isNaN` to filter off the zeroes.