# Search & Match in a text ignoring spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, search

I’ve indexed the text of PDF’s files on my database, but sometimes the text is not clean and we have spaces between words:

```
var text = 'C or P ora te go V ernan C e report M ANA g EMENT bO A r D AND s u PE r V is O r y bO A r D C OMM i TTEE s The Management Board has not currently established any committees.';
```

I want make a front-end search engine for my users, but I need to know the START and END position of each search (Based on the original text, with spaces).

I can do that with a regex, for example if I do:

```
text.toLowerCase().search(/m ? a ? n ? a ? g ? e ? m ? e ? n ? t/);
```

I find the word “Management” on start position letter 36. Now, I want know the “End position” of the word (Because I don’t know how much spaces are on the word, so I don’t know how much letters), and I want the search to be multi-matches (To give me the start/end position of multiple results).

Can you help me with that? Again, it’s very important for me to have the start/end position of each words based on the original text, removing spaces then search is not a good solution for me.

I’m also curious to know if I can do that without a regex.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return positions of a regex match() in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript)

Comment: Looks like you'd be much better off figuring out why whatever code you're using to index the PDFs is mangling the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demo might help:

```
> text.toLowerCase().match(/m *a *n *a *g *e *m *e *n *t/)
[ 'm ana g ement',
  index: 36,
  input: 'c or p ora te go v ernan c e report m ana g ement bo a r d and s u pe r v is o r y bo a r d c omm i ttee s the management board has not currently established any committees.' ]
```

(I modified your regex to use `' *'` between each letter, to match any number of spaces including 0. Your `' ? '` example would only match exactly 1 or 2 spaces between each letter.)

Using the `.match` method returns returns the captured expression and index (as seen above) if the regex is matched, otherwise `null`. You should be able to use this to do something along these lines:

```
const matches = text.toLowerCase().match(/m *a *n *a *g *e *m *e *n *t/);
if (matches) {
    const start = matches.index;
    const end = matches.index + matches[0].length - 1;
}
```