# how to convert to a date with a format i want when the retrieve data has a text on it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, momentjs

I have a retrieve data with a text plus date on it example below:

```
var textData = "Today is 2020-09-02 09:32:00+00:00"
let format = moment(date).format(MMM. DD, YYYY hh:ss A);
```

I want the output to be like this. `Today is Sept. 02, 2020 9:32 PM`

Comment: First step is to extract the date from the string. But as we don't know what kind of patterns you are dealing with, we can't really help. Also please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a match of a date like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy) (DD/MM/YYYY):

```
function parseDate(str) {
  var m = str.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);
  return (m) ? new Date(m[3], m[2]-1, m[1]) : null;
}
```

Second. Get position of the match (date) like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript).

```
var str = "this is a \"quoted\" string as you can 'read'";

var patt = /'((?:\\.|[^'])*)'|"((?:\\.|[^"])*)"/igm;

while (match = patt.exec(str)) {
  console.log(match.index + ' ' + patt.lastIndex);
}
```

Third. Taken position of the date use for getting substring. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Answer (score 0):

Using [`unusedInput`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/).

**Note:** Couldn't find a documented way to achieve this.

```js
var textData = "Today is 2020-09-02 09:32:00+00:00"
let mdate = moment(textData, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ");

console.log(mdate._pf.unusedInput.concat('').join(mdate.format("MMM. DD, YYYY hh:ss A")))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha512-qSnlnyh7EcD3vTqRoSP4LYsy2yVuqqmnkM9tW4dWo6xvAoxuVXyM36qZK54fyCmHoY1iKi9FJAUZrlPqmGNXFw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: what is the ._pf?

Comment: @nani10 that is an object holds some parsed data

Comment: what if I have a multiple retrieved text data and the other retrieved data has no date on it it makes the output Invalid date?? how can I check if the text has a date on it?

Comment: check my new comment please

Comment: Try `isValid()`. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/

Comment: How can I exclude on the ```isValid()``` the "Tomorrow, Yesterday" as a date??? It is considered as a date it returns a true