# Check if array includes specific items in specific order

Tags: javascript, css, string, dictionary

I need to change a background of a character in the span depending on inputted value. But! I have to check an entry depending on specific order of inputted value. For example, if i have inputted "Inv", i want to change a background only for 3 letters in "Inventory" element, not all "i", "n", "v" entries in the sidebar

This is what I have for now.

```
  backgroundColorSetter(item) {
    const spans = item.name.split("").map((char) => (this.inputCharsArray && this.inputCharsArray.includes(char)
        ? this._spanBackgroundSetter(char)
        : this._spanNoBackgroundSetter(char)));
    return spans;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of each match. Then, characters at index `i` should be highlighted if for any match index `m`, `i >= m` and `i < m + l` (where `l` is the length of your match):

```
const matchStr = 'Inv';
const str = listItems.name;

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295657/return-positions-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript
const re = new RegExp(matchStr, 'gi'); // Remove i to be case sensitive
const matchIndices = [];
let match;
while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    matchIndices.push(match.index);
}

const spans = listItem.name.split("").map((char, charIndex) => {
    const highlight = matchIndices.some(mIndex => charIndex >= mIndex && charIndex < mIndex + matchStr);
    // return ...
});
```

To make it more efficient, group the characters ahead of time based off whether or not they're in a match. Then, you only need a span for each change in background rather than for every character.

Comment: thanks, sir! how can i use it with ternary as i did in my example?

Comment: If you're just talking about inside the map, you can do `return highlight ? ... : ...`. Another option is completely remove highlight variable and just do `(char, charIndex) => matchIndices.some(...) ? ... : ...`

Comment: For some reason, getting "Aw,Snap" problem while using it.

Comment: "Aww snap" is a chrome crash, right? Only thing I could imagine is if there was an infinite loop or something--what do you have to comment out so that it starts working again?

Comment: hmmm...maybe the problem with while loop

Comment: If commenting out the while loop does fix it, I suppose you could print out what "match" is each loop. Be careful not to remove the "g" from the RegExp or else it will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help at all